# How do I edit values in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with values like these:

```
3.303.502.25

3.603.402.15
```

I want to edit them so they show up like this:

```
3.30 3.50 2.25

3.60 3.40 2.15
```

Code (i'm fetching it with selenium through chromedriver)

```
poster = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("outcomeCollection")
odds = [x.text for x in poster]
print(odds)
```

Here I'm getting the values:

```
['3.75\n3.50\n2.05', '1.28\n6.50\n10.00', '8.00\n5.00\n1.40', '8.50\n5.50\n1.33']
```

I want these to show as

```
['3.75 3.50 2.05', '1.28 6.50 10.00', '8.00 5.00 1.40', '8.50 5.50 1.33']
```

UPDATE:

```
for post in teams, odds_nested:
    cobb = {"Teams": teams, "Odds": odds_nested}
    data = pd.DataFrame(cobb, columns=["Teams", "Odds"])
    data.insert(loc=1, column="Home", value=odds_nested[x][0])
    data.insert(loc=2, column="Draw", value=odds_nested[x][1])
    data.insert(loc=3, column="Away", value=odds_nested[x][2])
    x += 1
```

It's not working, and I'm just getting the values for odds_nested[1]

Comment: You mean add space each 4 characters? what if it was like this? `3.6012.200.25`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: show your actual "array" in code. I am not quite convinced about how it is stored.

Comment: updated it @ParitoshSingh

Comment: There are 4 answers. You should upvote/accept helpful ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting strings separated by newlines. If you just want to separate them on spaces just do a replacement.

```
odds = ['3.75\n3.50\n2.05', '1.28\n6.50\n10.00', '8.00\n5.00\n1.40', '8.50\n5.50\n1.33']

odds_space_separated = [x.replace('\n',' ') for x in odds]
#Output:
['3.75 3.50 2.05', '1.28 6.50 10.00', '8.00 5.00 1.40', '8.50 5.50 1.33']
```

Additionally, it might be better to actually store the values as arrays if you need to use them later.

```
odds_nested = [x.split() for x in odds]
#Output:
[['3.75', '3.50', '2.05'],
 ['1.28', '6.50', '10.00'],
 ['8.00', '5.00', '1.40'],
 ['8.50', '5.50', '1.33']]
```

Edit: And to print the values in nested arrays, you can iterate and use the `.join` method.

```
for row in odds_nested:
    print(" ".join(row))
#Output:
3.75 3.50 2.05
1.28 6.50 10.00
8.00 5.00 1.40
8.50 5.50 1.33
```

Comment: Thanks, I got them as arrays now. But how can I access each value in the array and print them?

Comment: @Kingsmeister Updated. With values as arrays, you just need to iterate through each value and print/do any calculations as you see fit.

Comment: Would you know how to put each of these values in a DataFrame using pandas? Updated my code if you wanna see

Comment: yes, though i would encourage you to ask a new question instead, "one question per question" so to speak. @Kingsmeister See if you cant find a solution yourself first. (its as simple as calling `pd.DataFrame(odds_nested)`)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to add a space after each sequence of `X.XX`, a regular expression is a good tool.

```py
>>> import re
>>> data = [
  '3.303.502.25',
  '3.603.402.15',
]
# The `.rstrip()` cleans out the stray whitespace that would appear
# at the end of the string:
>>> [re.sub(r'(\d.\d\d)', r'\1 ', r).rstrip() for r in data]
['3.30 3.50 2.25', '3.60 3.40 2.15']

# You can also use `re.findall` if you'd prefer a list of lists instead:
>>> [re.findall(r'(\d.\d\d)', r) for r in data]
[['3.30', '3.50', '2.25'], ['3.60', '3.40', '2.15']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `replace` function of string with `map` function:

```
alist = ['3.75\n3.50\n2.05', '1.28\n6.50\n10.00', '8.00\n5.00\n1.40', '8.50\n5.50\n1.33']
alist = list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", " "), alist))
print(alist)
```

Hence each item of list will be altered.

Output:

```
['3.75 3.50 2.05', '1.28 6.50 10.00', '8.00 5.00 1.40', '8.50 5.50 1.33']
```